# How to pass parameters to restrict: 'E' directives to make template dynamic?

Tags: angularjs, parameters, angularjs-directive

I wanna rewrite some html into a directive but I'm in the dark when it comes to directives that use a dynamic template. Basically what I need to do is being able to pass parameters to the template so that I can re-use it with different values.

Now I've just passed parameters to the directive function but I know this is wrong. When you create directives that uses `restrict: 'A'` you can pass parameters like so:

```
<div error="somevalue"></div>
```

Which would then be available in the `attrs`. But how does it work when it uses `restrict: 'E'`?

How can I achieve what I want here?

```
forumApp.directive('error', [function(row, isRowAvailable, isRowUnchanged) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-if="row.model === "' + row + '">
                     <span class="error">*</span>
                     <div class="error-cell-inner" ng-if="row.model === 'row' && user[' + row + '].length > 0">
                         <span ng-if="' + isRowUnchanged + '"></span>
                         <span ng-if="' + isRowAvailable + ' && !' + isRowUnchanged + '" class="available">The name is available</span>
                         <span ng-if="!' + isRowAvailable + ' && !' + isRowUnchanged + '" class="error weight-override">The name is already taken</span>
                     </div>
                   </div>'
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This helps in understanding how custom directives work in a easy way. 
http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html

Try something on these lines. 
Here I am using AE which means I am allowing this directive to be used as Attribute or element. But you can restrict it to just E too.

```
<rb-add-button text="Add New Parcel" ng-disabled="!storeNumber" ng-click="addParcel()"></rb-add-button>


appRedB.directive('rbAddButton', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            text: '@'
        },
        template: '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> {{ text || "Add"}}</button>'

    };
});
```